# Disable/Enable Azure monitor alert rules by azure automation powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, alert, azure-automation, azure-monitoring

I have a azure monitoring alert rule where it will check the heartbeat of my virtual machine for every 5 minutes.
But, the virtual machine itself will go offline everyday at 11 PM and will be started again on 9 AM on next day.

so I'm trying to use azure automation to disable/enable my alert rule at the same time.
this is the code I've tried to use:

```
Write-Output "start job"
$vmResourceGroupName = <<resource_group>>
$vmName = <<vm_name>>

try
{
    # Connection
    Write-Output "connect to the VM"
    $Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
    $rcConn = Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint

    # Stop the VM
    Write-Output "Stop the VM"
    stop-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $vmResourceGroupName -Name $vmName -Force
    #first method that I use to disable my alert rules
    Get-AzAlertRule -ResourceGroupName $vmResourceGroupName -TargetResourceId <<my_resource_id>> -DisableRule
    #second method that I use to disable my alert rules
    Disable-AzureRmActivityLogAlert -Name <<my_alert_name>> -ResourceGroupName <<my_resource_group>>
}
catch
{
    if($_.Exception.Message)
   {
        Write-Error -Message "$($_.Exception.Message)" -ErrorAction Continue
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Error -Message "$($_.Exception)" -ErrorAction Continue
    }
    throw "$($_.Exception)"
}
finally
{
    Write-Output "end job"
}
```

both of the method which I use returning an error that said my alert rules are not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answers from Joy and Khrisna helped me solve this problem.
there's one thing on my end, because my Log Analytics Workspace was made last year,
it didn't support Get-AzScheduledQuery API.
to solve this problem you can either:
1. migrating your workspace to new workspace
2. update your workspace settings so it support Get-AzScheduledQuery.
   you can follow this tutorial to update the settings :

[Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log-api-switch)

hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I agree to what Joy has answered for newer metric alerts however if your alert is of 'Log Search' signal type instead of 'Metrics' signal type then you would have to disable the alert as shown below.

```
Update-AzScheduledQueryRule -ResourceGroupName "<resource group name>"  -Name "<alert name>" -Enabled 0
```

Illustration:
[image]

Related references:

1. [Update-AzScheduledQueryRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/update-azscheduledqueryrule?view=azps-2.5.0)
2. [Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/add-azmetricalertrulev2?view=azps-2.5.0)
3. [Get-AzMetricAlertRuleV2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azmetricalertrulev2?view=azps-2.5.0)
4. [Get-AzScheduledQueryRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azscheduledqueryrule?view=azps-2.5.0)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: hi Khrisna, thank you for your help. I also tried your suggestion, but it also returning a not found error. "Update-AZScheduledQueryRule : Exception type: Exception, Message: System.Exception: Error in getting Log Alert Rule 
---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> 
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'"

Comment: You would get this error if you provide incorrect resource group name and/or alert name combination. For illustration, I have updated the answer with screenshot that includes step showing the version of the cmdlets that I use (you may use latest Az PowerShell modules), pre validation step to confirm that a alert is enabled, step trying to disable alert with incorrect alert name (to reproduce the error which you got), step disabling alert with correct information, post validation step to confirm that alert is disabled.

Comment: Hi khrisna, just like my comment to joy's answer I think at least I got my resource group name right. because when I execute Get-AzMetricAlertRules all of my metric rules are listed up. but only when I try to execute Get-AzScheduledQueryRule it returning null

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mix the three type of alerts together, `ActivityLogAlert`, `metric alert(classic)`, `metric alert(new)`. They have different resource types, what you have created should be the `metric alert(new)`, which you can find in azure portal -> `Monitor` -> `Alerts` -> `Manage alert rules`.

If so, try the command as below to disable the alert.

```
Get-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -ResourceGroupName "<resource group name>"  -Name "<alert name>" | Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -DisableRule
```

**Update**:

Your `SIGNAL TYPE` is `Log Search`, its resource type is `microsoft.insights/scheduledqueryrules`. I test it with an alert the same with you, the command as below should work, make sure you use the correct resource group name and rule name.

```
Get-AzScheduledQueryRule -ResourceGroupName <group name>  -Name "<rule name>" 

Update-AzScheduledQueryRule -ResourceGroupName <group name> -Name "<rule name>" -Enabled $false
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi joy, thank you. never knew that azure has three kind of alerts. so, i tried your answer but it resulting in error : "Get-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Null/Empty, Code: Null, Status 
code:NotFound, Reason phrase: Not Found"

Comment: @oRoberto Could you find your alert in the portal? If so, please update the screenshot in your question, then I can know which alert did you create.

Comment: Joy, I've updated my question with the screenshot, and yes, i can find my alert at the list. now I'm wondering if I took the wrong resource group' name and the alert name. so I also added screenshot to show where did i get those two information from

Comment: @oRoberto See my update, make sure you use the correct resource group name and rule name, it should work.

Comment: hi joy. I think the problem is my Log Search type alert are not listed inside my resource group. because when I execute Get-AzMetricAlertRules with the same resourcegroupname all of my metric alert are listed up without problem. the strange thing is I only have 1 resource group right now. so I think it would be impossible for my log search alert to get assigned into a different resource group...

Comment: @oRoberto Try `Get-AzScheduledQueryRule -ResourceGroupName <group name>`, could you find the alert rule in the result?

Comment: @oRoberto Another way, go to the portal to disable the rule manually, use `Developer Toos(F12)` to see the request, in the request URL, you can see the resource group name and rule name clearly, then you can make sure you use the correct ones. Note the name will be encoded in the URL. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFEGy.png

Comment: Joy, I've tried the Get-AzScheduledQueryRule with only using the resource group name. but that's the strange thing, the result is returning null value while I have around 28 log search alerts

Comment: @oRoberto You test it in the runbook or in local? If in the runbook, try to update the `Az` module of your automation account, in your automation account -> `Modules`.

Comment: @oRoberto I test it in the runbook, it also works. This is my module version https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae7n6.png And looks the `update module` feature is changed, you could just remove the two modules and import again.

Comment: @oRoberto Also try `Get-AzScheduledQueryRule ` with no parameter to get all the rules in your subscription, will the result still be null?

Comment: hi joy, sorry for my late response.
1. I've test it on both local and automation with the newest az modules. but it still returning null
2. and when I tried Get-AzScheduledQueryRule without any parameter. it does returning some results. but, all of my alert with signal type log search inside my monitor --> Alerts --> Manage Alert Rules are on the result. 
does this means my alert is not a scheduledqueryrule type?

Comment: @oRoberto What `but, all of my alert with signal type log search inside my monitor --> Alerts --> Manage Alert Rules are on the result. ` mean? If it appears in the result, could you use `Get-AzScheduledQueryRule -ResourceGroupName <group name>  -Name "<rule name>" ` with the group name and alert name in the result?

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering instead of developing the custom powershell code for this. If you create this suppression rule, you can skip the part of disabling the alert for the VM in your runbook.

Did you try to use the Alert Supression (Action rules ) option. Here is the documentation for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-action-rules. You can try to schedule this with daily recurrence some thing like below using the UI and this will suppress all the alerts between the specified time.

1) Azure Monitor -> Alerts -> Manage Actions -> Action Rules(Preview). You can setup a rule like as below it will automatically supress the alerts.

[image]

Currently there is no powershell command(still you can use the arm api call) to configure the action rule, i heard that they were coming with one soon in couple of months time.

Comment: This seems as one hell of a resource, saves a lot of powershell/automationAccount resources.
Specially the filter object. But do I correctly hear you when there is no automation available for this resource. Tried to search this in every possible way (ARM, PS, CLI, even tried to searched in resources.azure.com but still no sign of it) So in the meantime to create a timewindow for the alerts the answer of @Krishna is the only option. (for log analytics alerts)

Answer (score 0):

Anyone look for solution , below command works set the disable or enable flag in this manner => Enabled:$false

Update-AzScheduledQueryRule -Name 'xxxname'  -ResourceGroupName  'xxxxrg' -Enabled:$false